# Assigning values to a new column based on values in an existing column

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(sort(rep(1:12, 4))))
colnames(df) <- c("A")
df
```

I wish to create a new column ('B') that assigns a 1 to rows where `df$A == 1:3`, a 2 to rows where `df$A == 4:6`, a 3 to rows where `df$A == 7:9`, etc. The result should look like:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(sort(rep(1:12, 4))))
colnames(df) <- c("A")
df$B <- c(sort(rep(1:4, 12)))
df
```

Here's the catch: I don't know how many values in the `df$A` column are equal to 1, 2, 3, etc. Furthermore, the amounts of rows for which `df$A == 1` and `df$A == 2` are not necessarily equal.

I know I can solve this problem by doing something like:

```
df$B <- ceiling(df$A/3)
```

What other ways are there to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What other ways are there to solve this problem? Thanks!

You can use the `%/%` function

```r
df <- data.frame(A = 1:12)
str(df)
#R 'data.frame':    12 obs. of  1 variable:
#R  $ A: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

df$B <- 1L + (df$A - 1L) %/% 3L
str(df)
#R 'data.frame':    12 obs. of  2 variables:
#R   $ A: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#R   $ B: int  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
```

Make sure that the use integers since you can find the following in `help("%/%")`

> `x %/% y` can be used for non-integer `y`, e.g. `1 %/% 0.2`, but the results are subject to representation error and so may be platform-dependent. Because the IEC 60059 representation of `0.2` is a binary fraction slightly larger than `0.2`, the answer to `1 %/% 0.2` should be `4` but most platforms give `5`.

Answer (score 0):

If `OP` intend to use the solution as part of `dplyr` chain than using `%%`, `%/%` and `tidyr::fill` can be another option as:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% arrange(A) %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(A%%3==0,A%/%3,NA_integer_)) %>%
  fill(B, .direction = "up")

#     A B
# 1   1 1
# 2   1 1
# 3   1 1
# 4   1 1
# 5   2 1
# 6   2 1
# 7   2 1
# 8   2 1
# 9   3 1
# 10  3 1
# 11  3 1
# 12  3 1
# 13  4 2
# 14  4 2
# 15  4 2
# 16  4 2
# 17  5 2
#
#...so on
```